# Do you find commonalities between existentialism and transcendentalism?

Tags: nietzsche, existentialism

As far as I can think of they both promote a sense of individualism but are they even comparable or do they overlap in any way?

Comment: Transcendentalism = Kantian? Please provide concise concepts and some context as to how you came to ask this question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'a sense of individualism' - could you elaborate, please?